# print(sklearn.__version__) NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
# Generate out datasets
dataset = make_blobs(n_samples=200,centers=4,n_features=2,cluster_std=1.6,random_state=50)
points = dataset[0]
## print(dataset)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

Isn't it possible to check sklearn version by print(sklearn.**version**)? Unfortunately, I got error which says name 'sklearn' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

you need to import sklearn too.

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```